# Create list from two uneven lists

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and it's intricacies, but have two lists of unknown sizes and contents that could look something like this

```
codes = ["or", "or", "or", "parks", "parks", "wa", "wa", "wa", "id"]
types = ["STATE", "NATIONAL", "STATE", "STATE"]
```

Each `type` relates to a non-distinct item within `codes` (e.g. `parks`->`NATIONAL`, `wa`->`STATE`), but the total number of `STATE`s are needed. In this case, 7 `STATE`s i=are expected.

My initial thought was to do something like this

```
var typesIdx = 0
var prevCode = ""

val totalList = mutableListOf<String>()
    
for (currCode in codes) {
    if (currCode != prevCode) {
        prevCode = currCode
        typesIdx+=1
    }    
    totalList += types.get(typesIdx).toString()
}
```

But I feel like there's a better and smarter way to do this that implements more of Kotlin's built in functions rather than simply for looping and creating the list bit-by-bit

Comment: Are the number of distinct codes equal to the size of `types`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood what you want to do correctly, you can use the [`distinct()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html) method on a list to help here. It returns a list containing only distinct elements from the original list, preserving the order of appearance.

```kotlin
val codes = listOf("or", "or", "or", "parks", "parks", "wa", "wa", "wa", "id")
val types = listOf("STATE", "NATIONAL", "STATE", "STATE")

// First, condense the "codes" list down to its distinct entries - which
// should make it the same size as "Types"
val condensedCodes = codes.distinct()
println(condensedCodes) // ["or","parks","wa","id"]

// Then create a map from code to type
val typeMap = condensedCodes.zip(types).toMap()
println(typeMap) // {or=STATE, parks=NATIONAL, wa=STATE, id=STATE}

// Then use that map to count the original codes list based on type
val numStates = codes.count { typeMap[it] == "STATE" }
println(numStates) // prints 7

// or if you want the list of states
val states = codes.filter { typeMap[it] == "STATE" }
println(states) // [or, or, or, wa, wa, wa, id]

// or if you want to transform the codes list to a list of types
val typeOfCodes = codes.map { typeMap[it] }
println(typeOfCodes) // [STATE, STATE, STATE, NATIONAL, NATIONAL, STATE, STATE, STATE, STATE]
```

The approach above will not work if the same group of codes appears in multiple places in your list. You can't use `distinct` any more, but it's still possible with the following approach:

```kotlin
val codes = listOf("or", "or", "or", "parks", "parks", "wa", "wa", "id", "or", "or")
val types = listOf("STATE", "NATIONAL", "STATE", "STATE", "STATE")

val condensedCodes = codes.zipWithNext()
                          .filter { it.first != it.second }
                          .map { it.first } + codes.last()
```

How does this work? The `zipWithNext()` creates a list like this

```
[(or, or), (or, or), (or, parks), ...
```

then it gets filtered down to only the first elements from the mis-matched pairs, essentially selecting the last element of each set of repeats. The last group is missed this way, so then we add `codes.last()` on the end.

```
["or", "or", "or", "parks", "parks", "wa", "wa", "wa", "id"]
              ^              ^                    ^          
[            "or",          "parks",             "wa"      ] + "id"
```

If you were going to use this in a lot of places you could define an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) (a neat feature of Kotlin) for lists

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.condense() = when(isEmpty()) {
    true -> listOf()
    else -> zipWithNext().filter { it.first != it.second }.map { it.first } + last()
}
```

to let you just use

```kotlin
val condensedCodes = codes.condense()
```

Comment: Amazing explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is correct, you just want to replace your  for loop with kotlin standard library functions and get the output of `totalList`.

You can do so in this fashion

```
val totalList = codes
    .groupBy { it } // Create a map -> {or=[or, or, or], parks=[parks, parks], wa=[wa, wa, wa], id=[id]}
    .values // Get a list of values from the previous map -> [[or, or, or], [parks, parks], [wa, wa, wa], [id]]
    .flatMapIndexed { index, v -> // flatten inner and outer lists while transforming each inner list
        v.map { types[index] } // In inner lists, replace [codes] element with [types] element
    }
```

In short

```
val totalList = codes.groupBy { it }.values.flatMapIndexed { index, v -> v.map { types[index] } }
```

Final output is

```
[STATE, STATE, STATE, NATIONAL, NATIONAL, STATE, STATE, STATE, STATE]
```

Point to be noted: This is less performant than your original code because of repeated iterations, as well as allocation of more collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
val codes = listOf("or", "or", "or", "parks", "parks", "wa", "wa", "wa", "id")
val types = listOf("STATE", "NATIONAL", "STATE", "STATE")

val result = codes
  .filterIndexed { index, i -> if (index > 0) i != codes[index - 1] else true }
  .zip(types)
  .filter { (_, type) -> type == "STATE" }
  .map { (code, _) -> code }
  .let { list -> codes.count { code -> code in list }  }
  
println(result)   // Output: 7
```

Steps:

```
filterIndexed: [or, parks, wa, id]
zip:    [(or, STATE), (parks, NATIONAL), (wa, STATE), (id, STATE)]
filter: [(or, STATE), (wa, STATE), (id, STATE)]
map:    [or, wa, id]
let:    counts how often the elements in [or, wa, id] appear in 'codes'
```

Note that the line with *filterIndexed* will result in distinct **consecutive** values. *distinct* would not work as @TylerV has correctly stated in his answer:

```
"or", "wa", "or", "parks", "parks", "wa", "wa", "wa", "id"
... would become
with distinct():        "or", "wa", "parks", "id"
with filterIndex {...}: "or", "wa", "or", "parks", "wa", "id"
```